# tkinter clock function error: NameError

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, tkinter

I have this function for a clock label in tkinter:

```
def update_clock():
    global clock
    now = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    clock.configure(text=now)
    clock.after(1000, update_clock)
```

I am getting this error:

```
NameError: name 'update_clock' is not defined
```

In all of the clock tutorials I have read they have the name of the function after the 1000 in that last line. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Can you post a larger portion of the code for us to understand where the error comes from?

Comment: The code above isn't [mcve]. It's not sufficient to reproduce the error you claim it does while not being minimal either.

Comment: The code you posted does not give that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did post `minimal` code this small example to help you resolve your issue, the error is telling you that you are calling your function before the widget is created.

```
import time
from tkinter import *


def update_clock():
    now = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    clock.configure(text=now)
    clock.after(1000, update_clock)

root = Tk()

clock = Label(root, bg="red")
clock.pack()

update_clock() # make sure you call this after you label has been packed

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you can comment if you are having challenges if not make sure you accept the answer for future reference.